# Google Talkback Building in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, accessibility, talkback

I have come across https://github.com/google/talkback and I really like the idea of releasing the code to allow contributions.

However, when I tried building this project, I ran into errors on Android Studio.

I tried `Import a project` and selecting this.

It's giving me errors because in the `/talkback/src.../TalkbackService.java` the package name does not match the directory structure.

Is there a quick way I could go about fixing it?

I can run `./gradlew build` and it works perfectly, however, I don't get autocomplete in the Android studio project.

I've the latest android studio and the recommended Gradle versions.

Answer (score 1):

Ishan welcome to SO.

Adding the below code to the main activity or launcher activity in the talkback-master project - manifest file.

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

I added to this activity in the manifest file. It did resolve the issue when I imported the project.

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.android.talkback.TalkBackPreferencesActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/talkback_preferences_title"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity="com.google.android.accessibility.talkback.SettingsAffinity"
            android:theme="@style/TalkBackSettings"
            tools:ignore="ExportedActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.accessibilityservice.SERVICE_SETTINGS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Hi Rohit, thank you for the response. 

I tried adding the launcher category intent. 

But I'm still getting package errors. [https://imgur.com/a/40XnEvL](https://imgur.com/a/40XnEvL)

I'm hoping this helps describe the problem better.